# Exception "SQLite Error - No transaction is active" in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions

In my project, I used sqlite transaction as follows.

```
var trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

var sql = "delete from table1";
connection.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);

trans.Commit(); // Here, an exception occurred: "No transaction is active".
```

What reason that cause the problem?
Who can help me?

Comment: Could you show more of your code? The code above is not valid (ExecuteNonQuery is SQLiteCommand's method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, I simply used BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

    SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "delete from table1";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "delete from table1";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```